# Tikz dimension too large when translating a fading line

Tags: tikz-pgf

In a large TikZ drawing, I am having an issue with a segment that I would like to add fading to.

This part of my drawing works fine

```
\documentclass[margin=3cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[shift={(30, 0)}]
\draw (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But then, if I add a fading to the segment like this

```
\documentclass[margin=3cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{scope}[shift={(30, 0)}]
\draw [path fading=north] (0,0) -- (0,1);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then I get the error

```
! Dimension too large. I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.
Continue and I'll use the largest value I can.
```

How can I add fading to my segment ?

---

Now if I don't shift the line, I don't get the error message either, but that would require shifting everything else in the image, and I would rather not.

Comment: You are imposing an enormous transformation on the faded stuff. You can avoid the transformation with `fit fading=false`, i.e. `\draw [path fading=north,fit fading=false] (0,0) -- (0,1);`, but this will not give you what you want, I am afraid (but avoid the error).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat with that, the line disappears completely. But so does the error ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "but this will not give you what you want, I am afraid". ;-) You can probably fix it by declaring your own fading which is sufficiently large. Or beg the maintainers of pgf to add the `fpu` support, a discussion that I do not want to enter here.

Comment: Try this instead `\draw [path fading=north](-1,0)(0,0) -- (0,1);`. What happens here is that Ti*k*Z **fits** the fading to your path, which is of width 0.4pt. This quantity is too small such that some inverse-matrix fancy shenanigan fails. By adding `(-1,0)` you expand the bounding box and resolve the problem.

Comment: Remark: this passes: `\draw [path fading=north,line width=2.6pt](0,0) -- (0,1);`; On the other hand, `2.5pt` does not.